# How to fix unreliable 4K Seiki display with MacBook Retina Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hdmi, display

I'm trying to use the Seiki 4k display model SE39UY04 with a Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013 MacBook Pro at 3840x2160 @ 30 Hz running Mavericks.  I've gotten it to work twice now on two different days, but upon returning my MacBook to the display and trying to reconnect, I'm now failing again on the third try.  Each time I've had to fiddle with it for around 45 minutes until I somehow got it to work.  At first it appeared that using SetResX was incompatible, so I uninstalled that and it seemed to help.  While away from the monitor, I added QuickRes as an alternative to SetResX, but now, even after rebooting multiple times and no longer running QuickRes, I'm unable to get the external display to work today.  The symptom is that the Seiki gives the message `Not Support` so it seems it sees a signal that it does not support.  I'm using the HDMI cable included with the monitor.

Are there any tools that I can use to help debug why this works intermittently?  Is there some kind of driver that needs to be updated?  Does this symptom suggest the HDMI cable is flaky?  Is there a good order to attach the screen relative to the built in display being on (laptop lid up)?

Here is output to /var/log/system.log after plugging in the HDMI cable:

```
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280380
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 62 modes for display 0x04280380 [36, 26]
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: CGXMuxAcknowledge: Posting glitchless acknowledge
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00003
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x2ac00003 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00003
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x2ac00003 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00003
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x2ac00003 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00003
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x2ac00003 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00003
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x2ac00003 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x2ac00003
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro Dock[288]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x2ac00003 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280380 device: 0x7feef1a035b0  isBackBuffered: 0 numComp: 1 numDisp: 3
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280380
Feb 12 10:13:37 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x04280380 [1, 0]
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280380
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 62 modes for display 0x04280380 [36, 26]
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Found 130 modes for display 0x003f003f [60, 36]
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003f changed state to online
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 130 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4cab, Model 0, S/N 1, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xb47a7eaf729dbd6e213a05bd7d4993d7, ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: GL mask 0x21; bounds (3840, 0)[1440 x 900], 62 modes available
    Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a00e, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xf7e52f93b4ac312e87ed39669f5c08b8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x000050db, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f0042: GL mask 0x40; bounds (2944, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 6, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000060, accelerator 0x00003523, unit 5, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (2945, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2946, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3: Startup Mode 3840 x 2160, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80000000, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1440 x 900, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80000000, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display added
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display removed
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 130 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, Vendor 4cab, Model 0, S/N 1, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xb47a7eaf729dbd6e213a05bd7d4993d7, ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7feef1a05530) - enabling OpenGL
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x000050db, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: GL mask 0x21; bounds (913, 2160)[1440 x 900], 62 modes available
    Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 610, Model a00e, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xf7e52f93b4ac312e87ed39669f5c08b8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x000050db, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f0042: GL mask 0x40; bounds (4864, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 6, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000060, accelerator 0x00003523, unit 5, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4865, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (4866, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x2ac00003 device: 0x7feef1a05530  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Feb 12 10:13:38 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280380 device: 0x7feef1a035b0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 12 10:13:40 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 12 10:13:40 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 4, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 12 10:13:40 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[95]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
```

Here is some of the system.log file from yesterday when the display was working and I was using the calibration software to make or use a profile:

```
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003c
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 62 modes for display 0x003f003c [36, 26]
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003c changed state to online
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x2ac00003
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 130 modes for display 0x2ac00003 [60, 36]
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 130 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4cab, Model 0, S/N 1, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xb47a7eaf729dbd6e213a05bd7d4993d7, ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004fdb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f0042: GL mask 0x40; bounds (4864, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 6, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000060, accelerator 0x00003427, unit 5, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4865, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (4866, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: GL mask 0x21; bounds (3840, 0)[1920 x 1200], 62 modes available
    Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a00e, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xf7e52f93b4ac312e87ed39669f5c08b8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: CGError post_notification(const CGSNotificationType, void *const, const size_t, const bool, const CGSRealTimeDelta, const int, const CGSConnectionID *const, const pid_t): Timed out 0.250 second wait for reply from "Microsoft Word" for synchronous notification type 100 (kCGSDisplayWillReconfigure) (CID 0xf5db, PID 684)
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3: Startup Mode 3840 x 2160, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80000000, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0: Startup Mode 1920 x 1200, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 2, ioModeID 0x80000002, ioModeDepth 0x1, IOReturn 0x0
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display added
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display removed
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 130 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4cab, Model 0, S/N 1, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xb47a7eaf729dbd6e213a05bd7d4993d7, ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004fdb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f0042: GL mask 0x40; bounds (4864, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 6, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000060, accelerator 0x00003427, unit 5, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4865, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (4866, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: GL mask 0x21; bounds (913, 2160)[1920 x 1200], 62 modes available
    Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model a00e, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xf7e52f93b4ac312e87ed39669f5c08b8, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7fd548d28810) - enabling OpenGL
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004fdb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:34 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x2ac00003 device: 0x7fd548d24410  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Feb 11 14:26:35 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280380 device: 0x7fd548d28810  isBackBuffered: 0 numComp: 1 numDisp: 3
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Feb 11 14:26:36 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3; ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}; TransferTable (256, 12)
Feb 11 14:26:36 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}; TransferFormula (1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 1 modes for display 0x04280380 [1, 0]
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x04280380 changed state to offline
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003d
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003d [1, 0]
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003e
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003e [1, 0]
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Received display connect changed for display 0x2ac00003
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Found 114 modes for display 0x2ac00003 [60, 20]
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro loginwindow[58]: CGSGetDisplayAliasList: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro loginwindow[58]: CGSServiceForDisplayNumber: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: MPServiceForDisplayDevice: Invalid device alias (0)
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 114 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4cab, Model 0, S/N 1, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xb47a7eaf729dbd6e213a05bd7d4993d7, ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004fdb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f0042: GL mask 0x40; bounds (4864, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 6, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000060, accelerator 0x00003427, unit 5, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4865, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (4866, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003c: GL mask 0x21; bounds (913, 2160)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, boot, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004fdb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: Unit 3: Startup Mode 3840 x 2160, CGSThirtytwoBitColor, Resolution 1, ioModeID 0x80001000, ioModeDepth 0x2, IOReturn 0x0
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display added
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display removed
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x2ac00003: GL mask 0x8; bounds (0, 0)[3840 x 2160], 114 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor 4cab, Model 0, S/N 1, Unit 3, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xb47a7eaf729dbd6e213a05bd7d4993d7, ColorProfile { 10, "Seiki Calibrated Expert"}
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01022727, GL mask 0x0000000f, accelerator 0x00004fdb, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f0042: GL mask 0x40; bounds (4864, 0)[1 x 1], 2 modes available
    off-line, enabled, OpenGL-accel, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 6, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01024400, GL mask 0x00000060, accelerator 0x00003427, unit 5, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 1024 MB
    texture max 16384, viewport max {16384, 16384}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003e: GL mask 0x4; bounds (4865, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 2, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (4866, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro WindowServer[107]: Display 0x003f003c: GL mask 0x21; bounds (4867, 2160)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, boot, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, ColorProfile { 2, "Color LCD"}
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro System Preferences[606]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Activity Monitor[765]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Dock[275]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Dock[275]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x04280380 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Finder[277]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Dock[275]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Dock[275]: uuid_callback_master: failed to retrieve UUID for display 0x04280380 (1001) (invariant failure)
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro System Preferences[606]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
Feb 11 14:26:42 ws-macbook-pro Dock[275]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x04280380
```

Comment: After fiddling around for about an hour, I got it to work at this point.  Last thing I tried was to bring up the display control panel and with laptop open switch external to scaled 1440x900.  Then I closed the laptop lid and there was a buzzing noise, flickering, HDMI1 message on screen, digital noise, and it failed after 5 seconds.  Opened and closed laptop again, and it worked!

Comment: One other note, I think the second time I switched the built-in display to be `Scaled` in the `Display` control panel, perhaps that is why second try worked, as now the main display is `Scaled` when it worked?

Comment: Watching TV through HDMI cable and hooked to Dish Satellite for the last 2 years and it was on 6 hours last night. All of a sudden, a blue screen and the "Not Support" phrase. Wondering how to approach problem, this morning and all was resolved. Thinking maybe HDMI cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the issues described, the Seiki monitor needs its firmware updated. The instructions on the Seiki website are incorrect for this monitor. Here are the correct instructions to update the firmware:

1. Download the .rar/.zip file and extract the "install.img" file to a freshly formated (FAT32) thumbdrive
2. Put the thumb drive in USB port 1 (the one on the back, not the side)
3. Turn the TV on
4. On your remote press the "menu" button
5. Then on your remote press "0" 4 times, that will take you into the service menu.
6. In the service menu choose the software upgrade option
7. Screen will display upgrade animation
8. Patiently wait for the upgrade to finish
9. Turn off TV when finished
10. Disconnect thumb drive

---

Updated Firmware links:

[SE39UY04_20130827](http://seiki.com/sites/default/files/support/Firmwares/SE39UY04_20130827.zip)

[SE39UY04_20130828](http://seiki.com/sites/default/files/support/Firmwares/SE39UY04_20130828.zip)

Comment: Where did you download the .rar/.zip file? The .zip I found off of seiki.com doesn't have a `install.img` file. It's also dated `08/26/13 15:08` (from inside configuration.xml file). Since I got the TV in 2014 I'm not sure this will fix anything.

Comment: @kelloti I downloaded off this page: http://www.seiki.com/support/downloads.php and for me I used this one: `Model # SE39UY04 – 20130828 With Backlight And color TEMP` http://www.seiki.com/Firmwares/SE39UY04_20130828.zip Are you on a Macintosh?  If so, Macs by default unzip the zip file and then install the img file so you see `install` folder instead of `install.img`, not sure how to disable, but unzip on Windows may fix the issue.

Comment: ah, thanks. I just ran `unzip SE39UY04_20130827.zip` in the terminal and it didn't expand install.img.

Comment: The URL is now:
http://www.seiki.com/support/download I like this video about the monitor in general:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiIbqyBBf0w

Comment: The new download page doesn't list the 39" anymore, but the files for firmware upgrade still seem to be available, just at different paths: The files are now at http://seiki.com/sites/default/files/support/Firmwares/SE39UY04_20130827.zip
and ... /SE39UY04_20130828.zip